# React JS: Implementing Show/More with respect to a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am trying to implement a `show more/show less` functionality with respect to a table. `Show More/ Show less` link should be visible only when there are more than 2 elements and show less should set it back to default number of items(i.e.2 in my case).`Show More` should print rest of the items. I am using react-table for the same.There is a data grid component where I pass necessary props, and trying to implement this logic in the child.

I have tried the following. Can someone tell where I am going wrong?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-ryiny?file=/src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMore: false,
    };
  }

  toggleState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showMore: !prevState.showMore
    }), () => {
      const subset: = this.state.showMore ? this.props.data : this.props.data.slice(0, 2);
    });
  }

  renderTableData = () => {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const subset = this.state.showMore ? data : data.slice(0, 2);
    return subset;
  };

  render() {
    const { showMore  } = this.state;
    const { data,columns } = this.props;
    const showLink = data.length > 2;
    return (
            <>
            {showLink && (
              <a onClick={this.toggleState}>
                Show {showMore ? "Less" : "More")}
              </a>
            )}
          <ReactTable
            showPagination={false}
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
          />
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'columns' is in the props not the state and if that is the only functionality you need then remove the renderTableData function

Try this

```
...

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMore: false,
    };
  }

  toggleState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showMore: !prevState.showMore
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { showMore } = this.state;
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    const showLink = data.length > 2;
    const subset = showMore ? data : data.slice(0, 2);
    return (
            <>
            {showLink && (
              <a onClick={this.toggleState}>
                Show {showMore ? "Less" : "More"}
              </a>
            )}
          <ReactTable
            showPagination={false}
            data={subset}
            columns={columns}
          />
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.Suppose this data is empty then how can I handle it with a text "No data found" ?

Comment: Initialize data with an empty array and condition render "No data found" component when data length == 0 or render ReactTable otherwise i.e data.length == 0 ? <div>No data found</div> : <ReactTable...